# Finding all real $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $a$ and $b$ are distinct roots of $x^2+cx+d=0$, while $c$ and $d$ are the roots of $x^2+ax+b=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Find all quadruples of real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that $a$ and $b$ are distinct roots of quadratic $x^2 + cx + d = 0$, while $c$ and $d$ are the roots of $x^2 + ax + b = 0$.

My initial thought was to simplify the equations and solve as a system, but this did not work. What is the best way to approach problems like these, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your system of equations approach will work here. We have $4$ equations:
$$a+b+c=0.....(1)$$
$$ab=d.....(2)$$
$$a+c+d=0.....(3)$$
$$cd=b.....(4)$$
From $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have $b=d. $
Substituting in $(2)$, we get:
Either $b=d=0$ or $a=1$. If the first case is true, then $a,c$ can be any real numbers such that $a+c=0$ and $a,c\neq 0$. Otherwise, we get, from $(4)$, $c=1$. So $b=d=-2$. So one quadruplet is $(a,0,-a,0), a\neq 0$ and the other is $(1,-2,1,-2)$.